# Validating rsync via SSH authorized_keys command="..."

Tags: ssh, rsync

I'm trying to validate rsync via sshd's authorized_keys file.

The problem is I can't manage to execute rsync from the validating script.

---

**Here's my authorized_keys file:**

```
command="/home/username/Desktop/valrsync username" ssh-rsa AAAA [...]
```

---

**Here's the valrsync script attempted differently each time:**

**Test 1 -**

```
$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND
```

Output -

```
$ rsync [...] / username@remotemachine:/
/home/username/Desktop/valrsync: line 2: rsync: command not found
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(601) [sender=3.0.7]
```

**And, more importantly, Test 2 -**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
os.system(os.getenv('SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND'))
```

Output (running rsync from the local machine and getting the output of `valrsync` on the remote machine) -

```
$ rsync [...] / username@remotemachine:/
sh: rsync: command not found
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(601) [sender=3.0.7]
```

---

I understand that rsync somehow spawns an instance of itself at the remote machine, and obviously that instance is not referred when I attempt to execute the rsync command via the script. rsync is not installed on the server, and I know it shouldn't be.

**Now the question is, what can I do about it (except maybe installing rsync on the server...?)**

Answer (score 7):

A better method than writing a homebrew script would be to use **`rrsync`**, which on Debian-based distros you should already have installed alongside `rsync` in `/usr/share/doc/rsync/scripts/rrsync.gz`. In that case simply run the following command to unpack the gzipped script into `/usr/bin/rrsync`:

```
gunzip /usr/share/doc/rsync/scripts/rrsync.gz -c|sudo tee /usr/bin/rrsync && sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/rrsync
```

(when already running as `root` you can obviously leave off the `sudo` invocations)

Alternatively [download `rrsync` here](https://www.samba.org/ftp/unpacked/rsync/support/rrsync).

**Reminder:** having `rsync` installed on the remote machine (the one with the `authorized_keys` file) *is a prerequisite* here.

Once that's done you can simply prepend a `command=` in front of a line with a public key, invoking `rrsync`.

Usually you would include some restrictive SSH options along with the `command=`, so it might look like this:

```
command="/usr/bin/rrsync -wo /data/backup/",no-agent-forwarding,no-port-forwarding,no-pty,no-user-rc,no-X11-forwarding ecdsa-sha2-nistp521 AAAAE...
```

By giving that directory (you can use `-ro` for read-only and `-wo` for write-only) you can leave off the directory on the `rsync` invocation.

So your command line would become `rsync [...] / username@remotemachine:` (mind the missing path after the `:`).

Comment: On some operating systems, `rrsync` is located at `/usr/local/bin/rrsync`. If you aren't sure, just good ol' `whereis rrsync`.

Answer (score 5):

The error you're receiving is `rsync: command not found`.  This typically implies that your `$PATH` environment variable is not set correctly.  Using your first test, explicitly set `PATH` to include the directory where the rsync command is installed.  For example:

```
#!/bin/sh

PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH

$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND
```

Make sure to make the scrip executable (`chmod 755 valrsync`).

All this assumes that rsync is in fact installed on the target system.

Comment: Thank you for your replay.
Is the only way to solve this is to install rsync on the target machine?

Comment: Yes, you need to have rsync installed on both the source and destination machine.  Rsync needs to run on both ends of the connection (because otherwise, what is rsync talking to?).

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have rsync installed and in the PATH on both ends (client and server). The rsync client uses SSH to execute rsync on the remote (server) end. That's just how rsync works.